# Error in translating apostrophe in module Path metatags

Tags: i18n-l10n

In module Path metatags if I set a text for all languages, a text with an apostrophe, all is fine. But when I translate that text to other language of the web, the apostrophe is shown as &#039 in that new language.

Any idea? Another characters, as accents, are shown fine.